# Difference between “thesis” and “dissertation”

Tags: differences, formality

Is there a difference between *thesis* and *dissertation* in a British academic context? I saw that *thesis* was more used at Masters level while *dissertation* at PhD level but would like a confirmation.

Comment: A quick dictionary search suggests that they mean essentially the same thing. I suppose it is primarily the usage that differs.

Comment: http://i.word.com/idictionary/Thesis

Comment: I confirm that I and many/most Brits use *dissertation* for a "lower" level. Except I wrote a *dissertation* at Bachelor of Arts level, and I'd call anything at a higher level (Masters/PhD) a *thesis*.

Comment: In my region, we would use *thesis* for all levels, and *dissertation* specifically for doctoral work. I have *never* seen dissertation used for a BA degree.

Comment: 'Thesis' has meanings that 'dissertation' doesn't have. A proposition, for one.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. I wrote a dissertation, not a thesis, for my Masters.

Comment: Interesting. I wrote a thesis, not a dissertation, for my Master's. Maybe it's a BrE/AmE split?

Comment: Maybe each school has a different local usage of two words which are relatively synonymous? Wouldn't be the first time...

Comment: I really can't see why this has been closed as being able to "be definitively and permanently answered by a single link..." - my answer was accepted and I cannot find a definitive link, everything is contradictory (hence why I haven't expanded on my answer).

Comment: Here in the UK they're interchangeable in common usage. I submitted `dissertations` for both my BA and MSc, though I always thought `thesis` has a more academic ring to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FumbleFingers says, the British usage is the opposite.  I would see the difference being that a dissertation is the discussion of a subject, as would be appropriate for Bachelors, and possibly Masters whereas a thesis is a proposition based on new research as required for a Doctorate.

Comment: This is the usage with which I am familiar

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate some authoritative usage examples, if any exists. For instance Cambridge engineering school uses both: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

I will take this as an answer if no additional information though.

Answer (score 0):

*dissertation* is normally for PhD only, and a *thesis* is used both for Masters and PhD.